# Почему заданный класс в условие с помощью js - удаляется?

Tags: javascript, form

**Summary:**

Хочется создать самописную форму, которая проверяет корректность ввода пользователем, то есть, заполнил ли пользователь поле или нет, в случае одного пустого поле,  пользователю `input` подсветится красной рамкой

**Task:**
В исходнике есть некое условие, которое проверяет с помощью `arrInput[i].value.length == 0`, но проблема в том ,  что когда кликаю по кнопке отправить, класс заданный `arrInput[i].classList.add("form__item");`  *в момент исчезает* . Пришлось останавливать скрипт через alert();

**Source:**

```js
let name = document.querySelector('form input[name=name]');
let lastName = document.querySelector('form input[name=lastName]');
let age = document.querySelector('form input[name=age]');
let send = document.querySelector('form input[type=submit]');


let arrInput = [name, lastName, age];


send.addEventListener('click', checkOut);

function checkOut() {

    for (let i=0 ;arrInput.length > i; i++ ){

        if (arrInput[i].value.length == 0){

            arrInput[i].classList.add("form__item");
            alert(1);
        }
    }

}
```

```css
.form .form__item.input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" action="">

    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
    <input type="text" name="age"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: Он не исчезает. У вас при сабмите перегружается страничка заново. Вам надо останавливать сабмит формы при наличии ошибок.

Comment: неужели event.preventDefault() ??

Comment: Да, в нем проблема была! Спасибо что не дали ответ,  а просто дали подсказку.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно оказывается добавить  в условие `event.preventDefault()`

```
send.addEventListener('click', checkOut);

function checkOut() {

    for (let i=0 ;arrInput.length > i; i++ ){

        if (arrInput[i].value.length == 0){

            arrInput[i].classList.add("form__item");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: _preventDefault_ нет нужды вызывать на каждой итерации цикла, достаточно вызвать один раз до или после.

Comment: И лучше не использовать событие 'click' на кнопке, а использовать событие `submit` на форме.